# Webview LoadURL removing token during call

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I am calling a WebView inside my application. So, the URL when passed with Token is auto authenticated by the browser(In Computer) and allows to access the page.

But, when i am sending the same URL( http://example.com/token=123424345534224)
in a WebView, the token is removed from the URL and i am not authenticated directly.

How can we achieve this.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_close_call);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvCloseCall);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://live.example.com/test/IncidentEntry/Direct?token=0qWqvfkh0fZMB46dXqp0d6ApANgXzvoA0XM1s5vHrt3B43fpdUgFgS4WMY2E%2FPQ8cVk%2FWins6VcSlzl8y0WR5ICr6ZkDH0X2WpVaFn%2FNh1Mo%3D");

}
```

Comment: how do you know the token is removed? try setting a webview client `setWebViewClient` and checking the url returned in `onPageFinished`

Comment: Thanks!!It worked!!!

Comment: Excellent news! Simply setting the `WebViewClient` fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes It Did!!! @Mr.KevinThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set a `WebViewClient` before calling `loadUrl`.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

For additional information on `WebView`, check out this helpful [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).